# Interact with Tezos in xamarin

Tags: contract, taquito, conseil, conseiljs

im searching for a way to communicate to the chain in my xamarin app. The problem is that the native libs like this https://github.com/mscappini/Tz.Net are not really well looked after so im searching for an alternative. My first idea was to open a webview and excecute some javascript in there. That way i would be able to run conseiljs and invoke contracts. I think that would work but i couldnt find a way to retrieve the contract storage in conseil and its probably hard to get the data back to my xamarin application. (i could print the result in the webview and search for the result with another js call but that seems weird) Do you have any other idea how i can solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is https://github.com/baking-bad/netezos, a .NET Standard 2.0 library for working with Tezos. You can easily use it to interact with Tezos node via RPC, manage keys (it also supports Ledger), forge and send operations, etc.

This library is actively developing (by the way, [mscappini](https://github.com/mscappini), author of [Tz.Net](https://github.com/mscappini/Tz.Net), is also working with us on Netezos [v2](https://github.com/baking-bad/netezos/tree/v2)) and soon we plan to release v2 with HD wallets, advanced smart contract interaction and more.

Comment: sounds great!!! i'll try it out. what do you mean by advanced smart contract interaction?

Comment: advanced interaction is expected to look like this: `dynamic contract = new Contract("KT1..."); contract.Transfer(from, to, amount);`, so you can invoke smart contract entrypoints like regular class methods, and pass "humanized" arguments rather than micheline

Comment: that does sound like an advanced feature for you to implement but a really user friendly way to use! Nice, but i figured out that to use your library i need to be familiar with rpc calls. Im currently not so i still need to figure that out. Its great that you are working on lowering the entry barrier to work with your lib.